# How to stop or release resource occupied by DULDefaultLayoutViewController in DJI UI SDK?

Tags: dji-sdk

I appreciate DJI's UI SDK. It is so useful for a developer who just wants to develop a simple project.

However, I got a problem to release DULDefaultLayoutViewController resource if I segue to another view. If I segue back and segue to the other view, the memory will be occupied more and more. Every time it tokes around 80MB memory out, and never give it back. In the worst scenario, it takes more than 500MB, until iOS system kills the app.

Is there any way I can suspend DULDefaultLayoutViewController video?

[image][image]

Answer (score 1):

Just like any other view controller, you can release the `DULDefaultLayoutViewController` and it should be handled automatically in a storyboard unless you are doing something special.

As for the video, the `DULDefaultLayoutViewController` contains a `DULFPVViewController` as its `contentViewController`. It's a bit of a black box today but what it does is hooking up the VideoPreview singleton to the fpvView. 
You can then control VideoPreviewer by accessing `[VideoPreviewer instance]`

Hopefully this will give you more finer controls over memory allocations.

Also, if you find issues with the SDK or UILib, feel free to drop them on the github project where it can be tracked: https://github.com/dji-sdk/Mobile-UILibrary-iOS